# jquery and using predefined function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a jquery plugin using a bootstrap class.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bsalert = function(klass, condition, hdr, msg) {
        if (condition) {
            this.html('<strong>' + hdr + '!</strong> ' + msg);
            this.addClass(klass);
        } else {
            this.html("");
        }
    };
    $.fn.bssuccess = function(condition, hdr, msg) {
        //How to read a selector????
        $(selector???????).bsalert("alert alert-success", condition, hdr, msg);
    };
    $.fn.bswarning = function(condition, hdr, msg) {
        $(selector???????).bsalert("alert alert-warning", condition, hdr, msg);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And i tried using this:

```
$("#successmsg").bssuccess(error==="","OK","you've done");
$("#errormsg").bswarning(error!=="","Error",error);
```

How do i read selector inside function definitions?

Comment: Simply use `this` in place of `selector???????`

Comment: Do you mean that you want the selector of the element that the `bssuccess` function was called on? If so, you can just use `this` within the plugin to get the element itself.

Comment: Thank you for hints. Thank you, Tilwin for error repairings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is passed as `this`.

```
$.fn.bssuccess = function(condition, hdr, msg) {
    //How to read a selector????
    this.bsalert("alert alert-success", condition, hdr, msg);
};
```

jQuery plugins use this to access the one, or more, elements to apply itself to.